# How to return json object on post request with message to ajax function

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to return json object with a custom error/success message using the same line of code on post request: i have these two lines of code:

```
return Json(data);
return Json(new { f = "error" });
```

I want to be able display it in one line like this:

```
return Json(data, Json(new { f = "error" }));
```

I know i can't have multiple return statements in my code. but i want to return the data with message.

My ServerSide Code:

```
if (getId > 0)
{
    var getList = appointmentRepository.GetAppointmentList(userId);
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getList);                       
    return Json(data);
    return Json(new { s = "success" });
}
else
{
    var getList = appointmentRepository.GetAppointmentList(userId);
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getList);
    return Json(data);
    return Json(new { f = "error" });
}
```

My Ajax Fucntion:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#tblAppointment').DataTable({
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
         ]
      });

      var table = $("#tblAppointment").DataTable();
      $("#saveButton").click(function () {

         console.log("appDate:" + $('.datetimepicker').val());
         $.ajax({
            url: '/Appointment/InsertPatientAppointment/',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
               appointmentDate: $(".datetimepicker").val(),
               patientRegNo: $("#patientRegNo").val(),
               reasons: $("#reasons").val()
            }),

            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (_data) {
               if (_data.f !== undefined) {
                  swal({
                     title: "Failed!",
                     text: _data.f, //"Ooops! something went wrong, 
                     record not saved,
                     try again later ",
                     type: "info"
                  });
                  table.clear().draw();
                  //table.destroy();
                  // $("#viewReportBtn").prop("disabled", false);
                  return false;
               } else {
                  swal({
                     title: "Success!",
                     text: _data.s, //"Appointment added successfully!",
                     type: "success"
                  });

               }
               $(".datetimepicker").val('');
               $("#patientRegNo").val('');
               $("#reasons").val('');

               var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data), function (el) {
                  return
                  el
               });

               if (arr.length === 0) {
                  swal({
                     title: "No Record Found!",
                     text: _data.f, //"Your search returns an empty 
                     result set !",
                     type: "info"
                  });
                  table.clear().draw();
                  return false;
               }
               table.clear();
               table.destroy();
               $('#tblAppointment').dataTable({
                  data: arr,
                  columns: [{
                        "data": "MatricRegNo"
                     },
                     {
                        "data": "PatientName"
                     },
                     {
                        "data": "EntryDate"
                     },
                     {
                        "data": "AppointmentDate"
                     },
                     {
                        "data": "Reasons"
                     },
                     {
                        "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                           return '<span class="fa fa-edit" data- 
                           toggle = "modal"
                           data - target = "#modal-Edit" > < /span>';
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  dom: 'Bfrtip',
                  buttons: [
                     'copy', 'csv', 'excel',
                     {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'Portriat',
                        pageSize: 'A4'
                     }
                  ]
               });
               table = $("#tblAppointment").DataTable();
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `return Json(new {data = data, f = "error"});` ? You cannot have two sequential return statements in one method. The second one will be omitted.

Comment: yes, that seems to work fine but it's creating another issue, record inserted does not show automatically on the datatable anymore until the page is manually refreshed, is there a way i can also make it show like before with the above line of code?

Comment: is there any way we can do that without the new keyword? if we don't use the new keyword, it's going to work fine as before.

Comment: How do you fill the table with data?

Comment: I have added the table script to the ajax function, please i will appreciate if you could look at it.

Comment: Change `JSON.parse(_data)` in this line `var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data), function (el) { return el });` to `JSON.parse(_data.data)`. This should do the trick.

Comment: yeah, that works. Thanks. Please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate the `data` object in your anonymous object which you are already returning:

```
return Json(new {data = data, f = "error"});
```

If you do it like this, you can access the data object in your ajax call like this:

```
success: function (_data) {
    var returnedData = _data.data;
}
```

Which means you have to adjust your `map` method call where you are preparing the data array for the table. Instead of:

```
var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data), function (el) { return el });
```

call it with the data object `_data.data`:

```
var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data.data), function (el) { return el });
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getList);

var returnData = new object[2];
  returnData[0] = data;
  returnData[1] = new { f = "error" };
  return Json(returnData);
```

Comment: Your approach is viable, but you should note that Ajax will always return 200 even if the server failed, forcing you to parse the property in the Json for the status.

Comment: That's correct but in this case perhaps he should change de Response type for IHttpActionResult or HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: You answer his problem, I posed the other approach you mentioned because I feel that is more natural and intuitive in a scaled approach.  But he did not specify, but you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would potentially approach in the following manner, extend the `JsonResult` to include a status code.  This way you can dictate the level of success to the Ajax request.

```
public class JsonResultWithStatusCode : JsonResult
{
     private readonly HttpStatusCode statusCode;

     public JsonResultWithStatusCode(object data, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
     {
          Data = data;
          this.statusCode = statusCode;
     }

     public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
     {
         context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
         base.ExecuteResult(context);
     }
}
```

Then inside your controller:

```
if(...) 
{
     var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);
     return new JsonResultWithStatusCode(model, HttpStatusCode.Ok)
}

else 
{
     var model = new { error = "..." };
     return new JsonResultWithStatusCode(model, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Then inside your Ajax you would be able to read the status code and then read the body.

```
.success: function(response) {
     console.log(response.status); // Status Code (200 or 500 based on above)
     console.log(response.data); // Our model based on above, one writing error the other actual model data.
}
```

All you would have to do would be read based on the server output.